# Object Properties Viewport Display Color Question

Tags: interface

Under what circumstances is the color in the Object Properties Viewport Display panel used?  I know I can use materials to get color to show up, but I can't figure out what conditions this color value is used in (as witnessed in this screen snap).  Googling shows that it is somehow connected to an 'ObColor' setting, but I can't find that in 2.82.

Thanks.
David

[image: Object Properties Viewport Display Tab]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Object's Viewport Display Colour is used when *Viewport Shading* > *Colour* is set to *Object* rather than *Material*. You can find this setting in the top-right corner of the 3D Editor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering this, was wondering that many times myself :).

Answer (score 16):

I will iterate on the other answer and add that you can also use this color to add variation to different objects which use the same material, not only in workbench but also in Cycles and Eevee.

In this example I used the same Material on all three spheres. I just tweaked the **Viewport Display Color** of each object. This a very simple example but it can have multiple applications.

[image]

In this example I used the values of the color to add a roughness variation between the objects.
[image]

Actually, you can use the three channels of the color (Red, Green, Blue) to add even more variation ! This is all the same material but the Red channel drives the hue, the green channel drives the roughness and the blue channel drives the transmission.

[image]

This behavior can be **key-framed**. This can be used to animate materials per-object easily. Both cubes have the same material.

[image]

How-to animate it :

[image]

Comment: That is pretty damn cool!  Thanks! (My upvote doesn't count because of my noob status - sorry!)

Comment: No problem ! I actually learned some tricks while editing my answer :)

Comment: That's awesome ;-) possibilities;-) BTW I was always bored set manually material color to Viewport that seemed to me something that should be default  and expected behaviour ... So now I don't have to 8-) how could I missed that.