# Animation nodes to shader nodes

Tags: shaders, animation-nodes

Can I use Numbers List to cycles materialoutput node in animation nodes?
I want to use numbers list to many objects which I made in Object Instancer node.[image][image]

Comment: Hi, could you had a few screenshots of your setup or more information ?

Comment: Hi,I added two pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168589/86891, you have to access a specific object's property in order to change each individual object if they share the same material. Each object has a few specific properties : Render pass index, viewport color, etc.

But you don't have to use the Animation Nodes for this since the shader nodes contains a "Random" -per object info which will act exactly as what you want to achieve.

[image]

However if you really want to use AN, use this setup in your shader :

[image]

And in your AN tree :

[image]

Comment: WOW!That's great idea ! Thank you.