# Trying to find a way to make a true pixel screen

Tags: animation, add-on, animation-nodes, matrix

Using UVs to animate the shapes on the screen would be hard and tedious so i want to use geometry to impact which dots light up

the compositor won't really help as it pixelates where the camera is facing rather than where the mesh is facing

when i used animation nodes the matrix wouldn't parent to my plane, and the rotation only affected the induvidual bounds of each sphere (which is what i used to make the leds)

something like this effect: https://blenderartists.org/t/animatable-pixel-matrix-display/1126033/11

[Can i make a mesh light up when something touches it?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177643/can-i-make-a-mesh-light-up-when-something-touches-it)

^ it's better explained in this new one i made

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What do you mean by *using UV map would take too long?

Comment: Related: [How to give an image or video a TV screen effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39508/78972), [How to achieve a realistic material for an operative phone screen?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118394/78972)

Comment: a uv map would be tedious to animate, i would rather use planes to change which "pixels" should light up

Comment: Any reason why you do not want to use the compositor?

Comment: it pixelates based on where you're looking, not where it's facing. The pixelation will not face where the plane is facing, only the camera

Comment: i'm trying to make a character with a monitor for a face

Comment: Hello and welcome, could you please edit your question and update it with all relevant information? As it currently stands it is unclear what you are trying to achieve, and it doesn't stand on its own. "*i'm trying to make a character with a monitor for a face*" Add these bits of information and also some reference images of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anyone able to help make a pixel screen?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177525/anyone-able-to-help-make-a-pixel-screen)

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Be clever and don't limit us by your own constraints in order to find a solution. There will be solutions using other methods you don not think of...

Comment: i tried a lot of methods, all of them failed

Comment: I personally don't think this hard to achieve... but I feel limited by your question.

Comment: How can i make it not limited?

Answer (score 2):

I still think UV map could be quite handy:

[image]

1. Scale the UV maps into individual pixels by scaling them to 0
2. Connect the UV map to Image texture
3. Use *Mapping node* to animate it

[image]

Comment: i was hoping to find one that didn't need an image texture and just used an emissive material, each 'pixel' would be impacted by a plane or geometry, much like how dynamic paint works, however the only problem with that is that it's slow

Comment: thanks for trying though

Comment: Hey :). Consider adding your comment to the original post - it makes it much more clear.

Comment: done and updated

Comment: is there any way i can make a second camera a texture output without rendering?
if so then i can use that along with this to make the effect

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely understand your question, but i think you need to sample texture? Then you can use `Texture Input` node. which is available [AN+EN](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/0hbbbc/) Branch.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Color with falloff | Animation nodes 2.1 in blender 2.81a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168586/color-with-falloff-animation-nodes-2-1-in-blender-2-81a)

this was the effect that i was looking for (the one posted in the answers)