# How to set transparent property per object for fade in/out, without having redundancy of materials?

Tags: animation, materials, transparency, eevee-render-engine, visibility

Before you comment:
**I don't want to have 200 materials of the same metal just for fading out at different times.
Render layers are out of the question too of course.**

*I bolded it out because I found here several quite similar questions and almost everytime someone who doesn't understand the problem of redundancy in complex projects advise to have the same amount of materials as fading in/out objects in scene.*

---

I am working on couple of animations where **lot's of objects** are needed to be f**ade in and out at different times**.

Since the projects are quite complex to manage for me (and I already have plenty materials) it is not effective to, for example, have 200 different materials of the same metal just for fading them in/out at different keyframes.

**Is there any way to do it using *maybe* Custom Propterties in object panel?**

I've tried using drivers on Custom Properties, but it always fading out all object sharing the same material.

Comment: maybe Animation nodes are the way to go? Also, do you have to control when the fade out happens for each object or can it happen randomly?

Comment: The animations ment to be an explanation of how mechanical devices work. Timing is very important here, it can not be done randomly (as it can be done via particles however).

Comment: You can use object viewport color to have per-object fading information. You can keyframe the viewport color of any mesh object. See : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163699/86891

Comment: wow great, this Object Info color seems to be a new thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWwS-0AHotY

Here it is how it can be done (in eevee too!):

[image]

1. Select an object (from outliner or 3d view, doesn't matter).
2. Go to the 'Object Properties'.
3. In "Custom Properties" panel click "New" (In my case "Custom Properties" Panel is at the top of all Object Properties Panels because I moved it - you may find 'Custom Properties' in your layout in different place)
4. Click the gear icon to configure your custom property.
5. The Pop Up will came out.
6. You can rename 'prop' to 'Alpha' or something else for better organisation of the project.
7. Click OK or Enter (if you click outside of the pop up panel, the panel will close without saving your settings).
   [image]
8. Add 'Attribute' node in Shader Editor.
9. Change Type to Object, type name of your Custom Property (in my case: "Alpha").
10. Now every object with this material and with Custom Property "Alpha" (in my case) can have it's own value of the Alpha parameter of the shader. Custom Properties' values can be change in side panel. If you use Eevee be sure to change settings of Blend Mode of the material (I prefer "Alpha Blend").
    [image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the object viewport color to force variation per-object, even if they share the same material.

The setup is quite simple :

[image]

If you are using Eevee, don't forget to tweak the blend mode and uncheck "Show Backface"

[image]

Add some keyframes and play :

[image]

[Further reading on viewport color](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163699/86891)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Little update:
Because the object color has 3 inputs that make difference in this soultion (Red, Green and Blue channel, the Alpha Channel is useless here), I also drivered these three inputs to Custom Propterty (called by me:)"Transparent". Now it is really easy to work with :) Thank you again <3

Comment: Objects with material's Blend Mode set up as: "Alpha Blend" are not being reflective in other surfaces. And their shadows aren't fading out... but just stay. 

Not a perfect solution for everybody, but it will work for me, as I'm not aiming at photorealism in current projects.

Comment: Did you try Alpha Hashed ? I'm afraid this is a limitation of Eevee

Comment: I tried but that creates very specific effect that I do not want in my 'clean' 'technological' , so sort of "kickstarter animations". 

I really hope that Blender Developers would figure that out one day <3.