# Unable to change the Material for all the objects in the scene. colour changes for all

Tags: materials, shaders

I have made a balloon doggo, and wanted to give each doggo separate colour, but I am unable to do so as when I select the desired doggo and change the colour, it changes on all.

I copied all the doggos from the originals ones so could this be the reason? However I am unable to find how the break the connection and assign separate material to each doggo.

[image]

Comment: oof. I suggest you try out this method instead if you don't want carpal tunnel syndrome https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/163699/86891

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75816/how-to-distinguish-material-and-material-slot/75820#75820

Answer (score 1):

Seems like instead of duplicate the object(shift+D)(no linked proprieties) you did an instance of the object (alt+D) (meaning the mesh data are linked)
Select the objects you want to unlink and type "make single user" on the search bar you can then choose if you want only the material to be single user, only the mesh data or both.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that in sometime and post results. But greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Did you use duplicate (`Shift-D`) or duplicate linked (`Alt-D`)?

This might be the source of the issue. You do not want the new object to be linked to the previous one.

Comment: I actually did Shift+D to duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that in sometime and post results. But greatly appreciate your help

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are linked-duplications, you can make each mesh single (header menu > *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data & Material*), but you can also keep the mesh linked to the other objects and separate their material: Go into the *Material* panel, and in the dropdown menu on the right of the material name, click on the *Object* icon. Now you can give a different material to the selected object:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try that in sometime and post results. But greatly appreciate your help @moonboots

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It worked.